# Use of longplural, shortplural in CustomAcronymFields

Tags: formatting, glossaries, acronyms

I'd like to have the first occurrence of my acronyms in emphasized style. So, I redefined `CustomAcronymFields` and use `SetCustomStyle`, as suggested by the FAQ. This worked til I needed a special treatment for a acronym. I guess the example is self explanatory? (Try it with and without `SetCustomStyle`.)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[%
  acronym, shortcuts,
  xindy={language=german-duden,codepage=utf8}
]{glossaries}

%see: http://www.dickimaw-books.com/faqs/glossariesfaq.html#longformat
\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
  name={\the\glsshorttok},% name is abbreviated form
  description={\the\glslongtok},% description is long form
  first={\noexpand\emph{\the\glslongtok\space(\the\glsshorttok)}},%
  firstplural={\noexpand\emph{\the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix}\space(\the\glsshorttok)},%
  text={\the\glsshorttok},%
  plural={\the\glsshorttok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix}%
}
\SetCustomStyle

\newacronym[
    longplural={A long Test},
    shortplural={AlT},
    plural={TSTn}]{tst}{TST}{A Test}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
This is aspecial long form of \acp{tst}. An the singular of \ac{tst} and it's
plural \acp{tst}.

\printglossary[style=listdotted,type=\acronymtype]{}

\end{document}
```

What do I have to change, to get the long plural and short plural working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in this case it might be better to upgrade to `glossaries` version 4.0 (which I recently uploaded to CTAN). This has a far more flexible way of changing the displayed format. Example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[%
  acronym, shortcuts,
  xindy={language=german-duden,codepage=utf8}
]{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
  name={\the\glsshorttok},% name is abbreviated form
  description={\the\glslongtok},% description is long form
}

\renewcommand*{\SetCustomDisplayStyle}[1]{%
  \defglsentryfmt[#1]{%
    \ifdefempty\glscustomtext
    {% no custom text supplied
      \ifglsused{\glslabel}%
      {% Subsequent use
        \glsifplural
        {% plural subsequent use
           \glscapscase
           {% no case change
             \glsentryshortpl{\glslabel}\glsinsert 
           }%
           {% first letter upper case
             \Glsentryshortpl{\glslabel}\glsinsert 
           }%
           {% all caps
             \MakeTextUppercase{\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel}\glsinsert}% 
           }%
        }%
        {% singular subsequent use
           \glscapscase
           {% no case change
             \glsentryshort{\glslabel}\glsinsert 
           }%
           {% first letter upper case
             \Glsentryshort{\glslabel}\glsinsert 
           }%
           {% all caps
             \MakeTextUppercase{\glsentryshort{\glslabel}\glsinsert}% 
           }%
        }%
      }%
      {% First use
        \glsifplural
        {% plural first use
          \glscapscase
          {% no case change
            \emph{\glsentrylongpl{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel})}%
          }%
          {% first letter upper case
            \emph{\Glsentrylongpl{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel})}%
          }%
          {% All caps
            \emph{\MakeTextUppercase{%
               \glsentrylongpl{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel})}}%
          }%
        }%
        {% singular first use
          \glscapscase
          {% no case change
            \emph{\glsentrylong{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshort{\glslabel})}%
          }%
          {% first letter upper case
            \emph{\Glsentrylong{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshort{\glslabel})}%
          }%
          {% All caps
            \emph{\MakeTextUppercase{%
               \glsentrylong{\glslabel}\glsinsert\space
               (\glsentryshort{\glslabel})}}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
   }%
   {% custom text provided by \glsdisp
      \ifglsused{\glslabel}%
      {% subsequent use
        \glscustomtext
      }%
      {% first use
        \emph{\glscustomtext}%
      }%
   }%
  }%
}

\SetCustomStyle

\newacronym[
    longplural={A long Test},
    shortplural={AlT}]{tst}{TST}{A Test}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}

\section{No Case Change}

First use plural: \acp{tst}. Next use plural: \acp{tst}.

\glsresetall

First use singular: \ac{tst}. Next use singular: \ac{tst}.

\glsresetall

\section{First Letter Uppercase}

First use plural: \Acp{tst}. Next use plural: \Acp{tst}.

\glsresetall

First use singular: \Ac{tst}. Next use singular: \Ac{tst}.

\glsresetall

\section{All Caps}

First use plural: \GLSpl{tst}. Next use plural: \GLSpl{tst}.

\glsresetall

First use singular: \GLS{tst}. Next use singular: \GLS{tst}.

\glsresetall

\section{Custom text}

First use: \glsdisp{tst}{sample text}. Next use: \glsdisp{tst}{sample text}.

\printglossary[style=listdotted,type=\acronymtype]{}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

**Edit:**

As from version 4.02, there's a simpler method:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[%
  acronym, shortcuts,
  xindy={language=german-duden,codepage=utf8}
]{glossaries}

% Define a new acronym style
\newacronymstyle{emfirst-long-short}
{%
  \GlsUseAcrEntryDispStyle{long-short}%
}
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-short}%
  \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \emph{\glsentryshort{##1}##2\space
   (\glsentrylong{##1})}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \emph{\Glsentryshort{##1}##2\space
   (\glsentrylong{##1})}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \emph{\glsentryshortpl{##1}##2\space
   (\glsentrylongpl{##1})}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \emph{\Glsentryshortpl{##1}##2\space
   (\glsentrylongpl{##1})}%
  }%
}

% Switch to the new acronym style
\setacronymstyle{emfirst-long-short}

\newacronym[
    longplural={A long Test},
    shortplural={AlT}]{tst}{TST}{A Test}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}

\section{No Case Change}

First use plural: \acp{tst}. Next use plural: \acp{tst}.

\glsresetall

First use singular: \ac{tst}. Next use singular: \ac{tst}.

\glsresetall

\section{First Letter Uppercase}

First use plural: \Acp{tst}. Next use plural: \Acp{tst}.

\glsresetall

First use singular: \Ac{tst}. Next use singular: \Ac{tst}.

\glsresetall

\section{All Caps}

First use plural: \GLSpl{tst}. Next use plural: \GLSpl{tst}.

\glsresetall

First use singular: \GLS{tst}. Next use singular: \GLS{tst}.

\glsresetall

\section{Custom text}

First use: \glsdisp{tst}{sample text}. Next use:
\glsdisp{tst}{sample text}.

\printglossary[style=listdotted,type=\acronymtype]{}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

The only difference is when `\glsdisp` is used. If you also want this to use `\emph` on first use, you can modify the above example as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[%
  acronym, shortcuts,
  xindy={language=german-duden,codepage=utf8}
]{glossaries}

% Define a new acronym style
\newacronymstyle{emfirst-long-short}
{%
  \ifglshaslong{\glslabel}%
  {%
     \ifglsused{\glslabel}{\glsgenacfmt}{\emph{\glsgenacfmt}}%
  }%
  {\glsgenentryfmt}% not an acronym
}
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-short}%
}

% Switch to the new acronym style
\setacronymstyle{emfirst-long-short}

\newacronym[
    longplural={A long Test},
    shortplural={AlT}]{tst}{TST}{A Test}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}

\section{No Case Change}

First use plural: \acp{tst}. Next use plural: \acp{tst}.

\glsresetall

First use singular: \ac{tst}. Next use singular: \ac{tst}.

\glsresetall

\section{First Letter Uppercase}

First use plural: \Acp{tst}. Next use plural: \Acp{tst}.

\glsresetall

First use singular: \Ac{tst}. Next use singular: \Ac{tst}.

\glsresetall

\section{All Caps}

First use plural: \GLSpl{tst}. Next use plural: \GLSpl{tst}.

\glsresetall

First use singular: \GLS{tst}. Next use singular: \GLS{tst}.

\glsresetall

\section{Custom text}

First use: \glsdisp{tst}{sample text}. Next use:
\glsdisp{tst}{sample text}.

\printglossary[style=listdotted,type=\acronymtype]{}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]